Dodge overlapping bars in tikz
I have such a plot and have now asked whether it is suitable from an academic point of view. It was suggested to me to ‘dodge’ the error bars (see here). Unfortunately, this is done with ggplot2. Is it also possible to do this in LaTeX and tikz?
This is the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \centering
            \begin{axis}[
                width=\textwidth,
                height=0.5\textwidth,
                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.1,
                ymin=8, ymax=16,
                grid=major,
                title={\footnotesize a)},
                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
                title style={at={(-0.15,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                legend style={
                    font=\footnotesize,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    draw=black,
                    rounded corners=3pt,
                    inner xsep=3pt,
                    inner ysep=2pt,
                    column sep=5pt,
                },
                legend to name=commonlegend
            ]
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,8.8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,10.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1b}
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,10) += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2b}
            
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3b}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\ref{commonlegend}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

And here you can see the overlaps, f.e. for $x=0.04$.


There is a way to do it:

omit error bars in the disturbing plot (at one point for example)
draw a copy with ONLY this poin, with bars, no markers, shift by coordinate values

Here is an example:
            % ~~~ VAR 2* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {   % not showing some error bar
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,10)                       % += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2a}
            
            % ~~~ shifting point a little, drawing only error bars ~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                no markers,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]            coordinates{
                 (0.041,10) += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
           };



BTW, the Inventive Principles used here are:

do a little less (i.e.: omit error bar)
make a copy (of addplot, with error bars)
make a system with shifted characteristics (well: the coordinates)


Some other remarks.
Separate drawing from main document
I described it several times, e.g. here, how to do and reunite this split. It gives you more freedom in design and less trouble with your main document.
Hence the peramble no focueses only on what's needed:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    %%\usepackage{acronym}
    %
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\usepackage{xcolor}
    %%\usepackage{subcaption}
    %%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

As a beneficial side effect all \figure, \centering, \footnotesize etc. becomes obsolet.
Let's focus on design now
However, in terms of design, conveying THE message(s), it can be useful to work with absolute width and height, like 14:8 (or any other aspect ratio you like). This one came out after some trial and error in having a more acceptable visual overall impression.
                width=14cm,%    absolute width and height
                height=8cm,

For the now shifted error bars you may want to consider things like:

reducing the gaps even further
changing the bars color or opacity
it's a balance between clarity and relationship ("me bar belongs to said data point")

Depending on your data and their nature you ma even consider using

halflog plot for y-axis (shows them virtually similar)
loglog plot, i.e. on both axes

E.g. the halflog would also be justified if you can expect a kind of exponential relationship between the data, while loglog will disguis any power function (x^n). // This is about conveying basic functional relationship, beyond "magnfying" the smaller bars.
Finally, the dashing is a bit two much to my taste. Consider replaceing by e.g.

similar, but different color, including tint or shade
having two similar but different line widths for varians a and b

Also, be more consistent in your line formats (unless I got it wrong) ... See Var 3a vs. 1a/2a etc.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    %%\usepackage{acronym}
    %
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\usepackage{xcolor}
    %%\usepackage{subcaption}
    %%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
%        \centering
        % ~~~ some refactoring ~~~~~~~~
        \def\barst{}
            \begin{axis}[
%                width=\textwidth,
%                height=0.5\textwidth,
%                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
%                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                width=14cm,%    absolute width and height
                height=8cm,
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.1,
                ymin=8, ymax=16,
                grid=major,
%                title={\footnotesize a)},
                title={Effects of some variants},
%                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
%                title style={at={(-0.15,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                legend style={
%                    font=\footnotesize,
%                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    at={(axis cs: 0.004,15.5)},%    absolute, in axis cs
                    anchor=north west,%             upper left corner
                    draw=black,
                    rounded corners=3pt,
                    inner xsep=3pt,
                    inner ysep=2pt,
                    column sep=5pt,
                },
 %               legend to name=commonlegend
            ]
            % ~~~ VAR 1* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,8.8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,10.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1b}
            
            % ~~~ VAR 2* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {   % not showing some error bar
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,10)                       % += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2a}
            
            % ~~~ shifting point a little, drawing only error bars ~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                no markers,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]            coordinates{
                 (0.041,10) += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
           };
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11)                       % += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2b}
            
            % ~~~ shifting point a little, drawing only error bars ~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                no markers,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates{
                 (0.039,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
           };

            % ~~~ VAR 3* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                error bars/.cd,
                error bar style={line width=1pt},
                y dir=both,
                y explicit
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3b}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%\ref{commonlegend}
%
%\end{figure}

\end{document}


P.S.
Here two more things happened:

abstracted common options inside the \addplot statements (refactoring)
changed appearance of all error bars at once (consequence)

In the preamble modify like this, where barst represents the common bar-style you were using:
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
            barst/.style={error bars/.cd,
                          error bar style={line width=3pt,opacity=.3},
                          y dir=both,y explicit},}


This simplifies your code, which is one of the reasons for refactoring (original Lines Of Code (LOC): 202, refactored LOC: 182 or 10% reduction in code size AND more universality gained):
            % ~~~ VAR 1* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                barst,% <<<<<<<<<<<<
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,8.8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1a}

Now you can play with changing bar line widths and opacity in one place only.
Of course you can, and perhaps should, have several such style-statements.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
    %\documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage{tikz}
    %%\usepackage{acronym}
    %
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    %\usepackage{xcolor}
    %%\usepackage{subcaption}
    %%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
            barst/.style={error bars/.cd,
                          error bar style={line width=3pt,opacity=.3},
                          y dir=both,y explicit},}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
%        \centering
        % ~~~ some refactoring ~~~~~~~~
        \def\barst{}
            \begin{axis}[
%                width=\textwidth,
%                height=0.5\textwidth,
%                xlabel={\footnotesize $x$},
%                ylabel={\footnotesize $y$},
                width=14cm,%    absolute width and height
                height=8cm,
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$y$},
                xmin=0, xmax=0.1,
                ymin=8, ymax=16,
                grid=major,
%                title={\footnotesize a)},
                title={Effects of some variants},
%                tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
%                title style={at={(-0.15,1.15)}, anchor=north west},
                xtick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10},
                xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                legend style={
%                    font=\footnotesize,
%                    legend columns=-1,
                    cells={anchor=west},
                    at={(axis cs: 0.004,15.5)},%    absolute, in axis cs
                    anchor=north west,%             upper left corner
                    draw=black,
                    rounded corners=3pt,
                    inner xsep=3pt,
                    inner ysep=2pt,
                    column sep=5pt,
                },
 %               legend to name=commonlegend
            ]
            % ~~~ VAR 1* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                barst,
            ] 
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,8.8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,9.2) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=red,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,8.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,10.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 1b}
            
            % ~~~ VAR 2* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates {   % not showing some error bar
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,10)                       % += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2a}
            
            % ~~~ shifting point a little, drawing only error bars ~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                no markers,
                solid,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates{
                 (0.041,10) += (0,2.6) -= (0,0.1)
           };
            
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,9.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11)                       % += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 2b}
            
            % ~~~ shifting point a little, drawing only error bars ~~~
            \addplot[
                color=blue,
                no markers,
                solid,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates{
                 (0.039,11) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
           };

            % ~~~ VAR 3* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=*,
                solid,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,11.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,12.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,13.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3a}
            
            \addplot[
                color=orange,
                mark=square*,
                densely dashed,
                barst,
            ]
            coordinates {
                (0.00,8) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.02,10) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.04,12) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.06,13) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.08,14) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
                (0.10,14.5) += (0,0.3) -= (0,0.1)
            };
            \addlegendentry{Variant 3b}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
%\ref{commonlegend}
%
%\end{figure}

\end{document}

